# Display the triangle pointStyle of chartjs upside down

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

Is it possible to make the `pointStyle: 'triangle'` of Chart.js upside down?

I've been searching the net for hours trying to find the solution on how to reverse the triangle but there seem to be no solution yet, as far as my research is concerned (or maybe I'm just looking at the wrong direction).

I'm currently working on an anesthesia record. This image is what my graph looks like right now. I want to make the red triangles(systolic) upside down:

[image: what my graph look like right now, I want to make the red triangles(systolic) upside down]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `rotation` property of the [point configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#point-configuration) to control how the points are drawn.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "scatter",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      pointStyle: 'triangle',
      rotation: 60,
      radius: 20, // just here to make the points very visible
      data: [{
        x: 1,
        y: 1
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 2
      }, {
        x: 3,
        y: 3
      }]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: I've tried using the rotation/pointRotation property yesterday, I can't figure out why it doesn't work. the type of graph I'm using is Line, I just set the showLine property to false. Do you think it has anything to do with it?

Comment: @AngelieHerrera The type of chart shouldn’t matter. Make sure you are using the latest Chart.js version (currently 2.8.0). Otherwise, please edit your question to include your code showing the problem.